# A fast way to set values of a 2d vector to 0

Tags: c++, vector

Given the following example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include<iterator>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<T>& v){
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<T>(os, "  "));
    return os;
}


int main (){

vector<int>vec;
vector<vector<int>> x(10,vector<int>());
for(int i=0; i< x.size(); i++)
    x[i].resize((rand() % 100 + 1), 10);

for(int i=0; i< x.size(); i++)
    fill(x[i].begin(),x[i].end(),0);

return 0;
}
```

What would be the fastest way to set the values in the second vector to 0

thnx

Comment: What is "the second vector"?

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the question, or is it completely unnecessary to set all of the values to 0 because they will be value-initialized during the `resize`?

Comment: Get rid of the nesting. Have a vector storing _n*m_ `int`s, zero-initiliase that, and wrap access-by-index to fake two-dimensionality.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit what are you suggesting `n` and `m` are? The rows have random lengths.

Comment: @user2079303: Well yeah okay if it's a jagged array then this is not going to work you're right :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is completely unnecessary to fill the inner `std::vector`s with zeroes, because `resize` default-inserts new elements into the vectors which value-initializes them. In the case of `int`s, value-initialization means setting them to 0.

---

It can be a little difficult to determine this from the standard, so here's the trail (from N4296 - the C++14 draft):

From the definition of `resize`:

> If `size() < sz`, appends `sz - size()` default-inserted elements to the sequence.

The definition of `default-inserted`:

> An element of `X` is default-inserted if it is initialized by evaluation of the expression
>
> ```
> allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p)
> ```
>
> where `p` is the address of the uninitialized storage for the element allocated within `X` [and `m` is an allocator of type `A`].

Definition of `allocator_traits<A>::construct`:

> ```
> template <class T, class... Args>
> static void construct(Alloc& a, T* p, Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> Effects: calls `a.construct(p, std::forward<Args>(args)...)` if that call is well-formed; otherwise, [...].

From the definition of an allocator:

> ```
> a.construct(c, args)
> ```
>
> Effect: Constructs an object of
>   type C at c
>
> Default: `::new ((void*)c) C(forward<Args>(args)...)`

From the definition of the `new`-expression:

> - If the new-initializer is omitted, [...]
> - Otherwise, the new-initializer is interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for direct-initialization.

From the definition of direct-initialization:

> - [...]
> - If the initializer is (), the object is value-initialized.
> - [..]

Value-initialization:

> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type with [...];
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type with [...];
> - if T is an array type, then [...];
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

Zero-initialization:

> - if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is initialized to the value obtained by converting the integer literal 0 (zero) to T;
> - if [...]

Comment: Excellent observation.-- Interestingly, my copy of the standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2011(E)) says in 23.3.6.3/9 "If size() < sz, appends sz - size() **value-initialized** elements". (emphasis mine). Per 8.5/7 "value-initialize" means "otherwise [i.e. no class or array], the object is zero-initialized."

Comment: @PeterSchneider This might be newer terminology (I used the latest draft - basically C++14). I suppose they wanted to be more explicit about the use of the allocator? I don't have any other specs at hand to check. The result is the same, however!

Comment: The final wording is much simpler. I assume the allocator is irrelevant for the zeroing.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Sorry, I mean my wording was newer (since it's coming from the C++14 draft). I can't find the issue/paper that changed this though (would like to see the rationale).

Comment: Oh. Right, mine is the C++11 standard. Then I change my assumption and conclude that there are subtle initialization dependencies on the allocator ;-).

Comment: There is a hint in no. 2274 of http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html. It's about map::operator[]  (but vector::resize() is mentioned as an aside): "Not to mention that default-insertion is more useful, because it allows custom allocators to "override" the default value of mapped_type."

Comment: @PeterSchneider Good find. I noticed that the wording changed for `std::vector` between N3337 and N3376.

Comment: It's also interesting to note that explicitly zeroing may not only be inefficient but semantically wrong (because a non-zeroing allocator will be non-zeroing for a reason).

Answer (score 1):

In your example it's simplest and fastest to initialize the vectors with zeroes initially. In the constructor of the parent vector if they are same length, or in the resize if the vectors are random lengths.

If you have an existing vector of vectors with old values and you want to set them all to zero, then `memset` is usually the fastest way. Since vector is guaranteed to have contiguous storage and your inner vectors don't contain complex (non-POD) objects, it's safe to use `memset`

```
for(auto& v : x)
    std::memset(&v[0], 0, sizeof(v[0]) * v.size());
```

That said, `std::fill_n` or `std::fill` is *probably* just as fast and is not limited to POD/builtin objects and is easier to read so I recommend using that instead. Benchmark your code if you have a bottleneck and see if you gain anything with `memset` on your targeted platform. Otherwise, stick with what you have.

Answer (score 1):

Use the vector::vector(count, value) constructor which accepts the initial value. In the below case, it will be set to zero.

```
vector< vector<int> > yourVector(value1, vector<int>(value2)); 

// initial value will be zero
```

Comment: But the asker wants random sized vectors. I don't think this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11

```
for (auto &i : x)
    std::fill(i.begin(), i.end(), 0);
```

or (before C++11)

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator i=x.begin(), end = x.end(); i != end; ++i)
    std::fill(i.begin(), i.end(), 0);
```

will be hard to beat - and will probably beat a loop using an index (as in `x[i]`).